# How to create a metadata search web part view from multiple (4) document library's?

Tags: list, document-library, search

I need to be able to search in 4 document library's for a particular metadata field that is available in all document library's.

Is there any out of the box feature for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SharePoint online or 2013 try creating a search result source: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-result-sources-fd8d6ac6-c5d0-454d-80a9-51580902b25d. This allows you to transform your search query so that only the metadata field is search, which should result only in items from your document libraries. There are also other options to finetune the results.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your life. Use a common Content Type for all 4 libraries. Then create a Result Source like `ContentType=MyContent`. Then apply the query to the Result Source. If you cannot create the result source then just add that query to your web part or rule.

If you can't or won't create the Content Type then you can use Path, but IMHO that's yucky.